# trouble with WHERE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi guys im using this MYSQL query to get the top uploader users and the total of thier images views in the current month :

```
    $users = DB::query("SELECT * ,
  COUNT(p.id) as numPics,
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews

FROM
  images p 
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
 WHERE 
 p.created_at >= \"$current_month\"
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY totalViews DESC LIMIT 10");
```

the trouble that the totalViews return the total of views of all pictures , what i want is to get the total of views of the pics uploaded in the current month .
thanks .

Comment: can you put the direct where can i find the solution bcz the full code works fine except what i posted .

Comment: did u try subquery pls try u might get result

Comment: can put some exmaple plz ?

Comment: SELECT * ,
  COUNT(p.id) as numPics,(select 
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews where user_id=p.id) try something like this

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p.created_at >= "2013-05-01 23:59:59")

Comment: @Hamza you may want to read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [using parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use **MONTH(NOW())** in mysql for getting data for current month

```
p.created_at >= MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't directly answer the question. Consider expanding your answer to identify the OP's current problem.

Comment: im using this structure : $current_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of this month")) . ' 23:59:59';

Comment: what is the data type of column `created_at`?

Comment: @Hamza: In mysql itself there is func for getting current month. Then  why should you go for getting current month using php and implementing in query?

Comment: Hmm, would it be this simple: change `strto*time*` in `strto*date*`?

Comment: it doesn't make a diffrent VinothBabu i have now just how to make a where  in the SUM function .

Comment: @YahooSerious `strtodate()` is not a PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

change the group by statement and the select clause to this

```
SELECT * ,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images where id = p.id) as numPics,
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews

FROM
  images p 
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
 WHERE 
 p.created_at >= \"$current_month\"
GROUP BY p.user_id, p.id
ORDER BY totalViews DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [extract method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

```
"SELECT * ,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images where id = p.id) as numPics,
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews

FROM
  images p 
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
 WHERE 
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM p.created_at) >= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM \"$current_month\")
GROUP BY p.user_id, p.id
ORDER BY totalViews DESC LIMIT 10"
```

The name of variable is miss-leading i.e $current_month , but your comments says it has a time stamp value e.g "2013-05-01 23:59:59"

Answer (score 0):

This query looks like a perfect example to make it a little more generic. When you add an upper limit for `created_at` you can use the same query also to find the top of last month (or any other month).

```
$lower_limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
$upper_limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

I do assume that you're using PDO [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), so I'll just provide the SQL.

```
SELECT u.*,
  COUNT(p.id) as numPics,
  SUM(p.views) as totalViews
FROM
  images p 
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
  p.created_at >= :lower_limit
AND p.created_at < :upper_limit
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY totalViews DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Note that this does not selecting any images. The result set should be consistent, and when you group by user_id you have no control over the image data in the result set.